# Software can not be verified warning

Tags: 13.04, updates, update-manager, software-updater

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 with KDE. Today, Software update notification indicated security updates containing updates to libfs6, libx11-6, libx11-data, etc.

When proceed with the updates, it asks for my password and then gives a message:

```
The following pieces of software cannot be verified. WARNING: Installing unverified software represents a security risk, as the presence of unverifiable software can be a sign of tampering. Do you wish to continue/ cancel
```

I have, of course, canceled updates. What could be the issue/ how do I set it right? More importantly, is my system hacked/ compromised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this means that you have an old copy of Ubuntu's APT keys (used to verify that the packages you're installing are legit); you probably have not been hacked. Does it continue to happen after a `sudo apt-get update` to get the latest keys?

Here's a basic intro: http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt

> Another problem you may encounter if using testing or unstable is that if you have not run apt-get update lately and apt-get install a package, apt might complain that it cannot be authenticated (why does it do this?). apt-get update will fix this.

Comment: Perfect. sudo apt-get update did the trick.