# libcgmanager0 is not verified by authors

Tags: 14.04, updates, kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 and I use the software center for updates, which usually works fine, but now there was an error message as in the title.

I am not really sure what to do about this, so I canceled the update.

Is there a way to verify the package?

It's also a bit weird that the exact same package appears two times in the list of available updates. It is Version `0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1`

If I recall correctly, the same thing happened with the same packages some while ago, and that time I also canceled the update.

Other packages are completely fine.

I tried `sudo apt-get update`, which made the package go away (last time I also did that, but it seems that after a while the packages came back), so it seems to be different from [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/305527/231418) question.

This is the output of `apt-cache policy libcgmanager0`, I'm sorry it's in German, but I hope it's still intelligible.

```
$ apt-cache policy libcgmanager0  
libcgmanager0:
  Installiert:           0.24-0ubuntu7.5
  Installationskandidat: 0.24-0ubuntu7.5
  Versionstabelle:
     0.39-2ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main   amd64 Packages
 *** 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 0
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.24-0ubuntu7.1 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.24-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit: It happened again today (4th Jan 2016) and I still don't know what to do about this.

Edit2: It happened again on 12th Feb 2016. I still cancelled the update.

It's still the `libcgmanager0`.